# Compare two instance of COM interface based on value

Tags: windows, com

Is there an established pattern on how to compare two COM-objects based on their value (aka private state), instead of their identity (aka pointer to IUnknown)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Object equality is a heavy implementation detail, a detail that's well hidden in COM.  COM is an interface based object model, the fact that an implementation is required of those interfaces is carefully hidden.  It comes up in just a few places, CoCreateInstance() being the obvious one.  Less obvious are the rules for IUnknown.  Whose proper implementation requires that you'll get the same IUnknown interface pointer when you QI through any of the implemented interfaces.  This provides object identity, not object equality.

There is no standard COM interface type that is commonly used to test object equality.  You'll just have to make your own.  A simple one with an IsEqualTo() method gets the job done.  Or you could just add that method to your default interface.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on definition of "private state". A COM object does not have to have one. If the objects implement `IPersist*` family of interfaces, esp. `IPersistStreamInit`, then you can [save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) both into persistent stream or property bag, and then compare storages directly, such as byte-by-byte comparison of the streams.

Comment: Let's assume the object in question has a private state (e.g. a std::list - just to make serialization a 100% non-option...)

Comment: So you will serialize private persistent data into stream, then you will do byte comparison of the streams.

Comment: That sound's awfully expensive... (especially with really big objects)

Comment: It is expensive, because you are asking for a generic pattern. A class specific comparison might be definitely way more efficient.

Comment: Thinking about how .NET/Java do arbitrary value comparisons: shouldn't the CLSID be an indicator if the two objects have the same type? (assuming that I have a reliably way to extract that information from any object). If the CLSIDs of two objects are the same doesn't that imply that they are of the same (internal) implementation type?

Comment: `1` COM objects don't have to have CLSID, and `2` COM objects don't have to reveal their CLSIDs even if they "have" them. `3` Knowing CLSID does not mean they are "of the same type". `4` having objects of the same type as a fact of life, you still do not have a generic method to compare their "private states" efficiently.

Comment: Now I'm totally confused. How can a COM object not have a CLSID? How can it be created if there's no CLSID? As the CLSID is meant to represent a component type how can 2 identical CLSIDs not indicate that the objects are of the same type?

Comment: @MFH You don't need to use CoCreateInstance to create a COM object. You can ask an existing interface to create one for you, for example.